# Socket.io Deleting a marker on disconnect

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a project that plots markers on a map when a user logs in.
however the markers are staying after the user logs out.

I am trying to write a disconnect function to destroy just that marker.
but it is not working.

Do I need anything client side?

SERVER SIDE

```
// Socket markers start

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

socket.on('marker', function(data) {
  data.socketId = socket.id;
  User.findById(socket.request.session.passport.user, function(err,    user){
    if(user){
      data.socketId = socket.id;
      data.user = user;
      markers.push(data);
      console.log(markers);
      // markers[socket.id] = data;

      io.emit('show-marker', markers);
    }
  });
});
// socket.on('show-marker', )
socket.on('show-user-location', function(data) {
  io.emit('show-user-location', data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log( socket.name + ' has disconnected from the chat.' + socket.id);
  delete markers[socket.id];
});


});
```

Comment: How is client side supposed to know to remove the marker? Shouldn't you emit '`'show-marker'` event again with updated list of markers after deleting with `delete markers[socket.id]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `markers` is an array, since you use `push`. So `delete markers[socket.id]` doesn't work properly. You must search for it - iterate over all the items, check if id matches and then use `splice`.

So it's best to use `Object` for storing markers like:

```
// on connect
markers[data.id] = data;

// on disconnect
delete markers[socket.id]
```

If you still want to use an array, this will work for you:

```
// on disconnect
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { // loop through all markers
    if (socket.id == markers[i].id) { // find the one you need
        markers.splice(i, 1); // remove it from array
        break; // stop searching - already found it
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes correct an array...
so we need to delete the correct marker by checking?

     socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      for(i=0; i<(markers.length- 1); i++){
        if(socket.id === ){
      delete markers[socket.id];
        }
      }

Comment: Updated my answer to include array usage.